# How can I ascertain that .NET NegotiateStream [MS-NNS] established a secure connection?

Tags: tls, tcp

I have a WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) application using the netTcpBinding.

Server configuration:

```
<netTcpBinding>
  <binding name="defaultNetTcpBinding">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" sslProtocols="Tls12">
        <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Always" />
      </transport>
    </security>
  </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

Client configuration:

```
<netTcpBinding>
  <binding name="netTcpEndpointAuth">
    <security mode="Transport">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" sslProtocols="Tls12" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

Using netmon 3.4, I'm able to capture the traffic between the client and the server.  I can see the TCP and the [MS-NNS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-nns/93df08eb-a6c4-4dff-81c3-519cf7236df4) communication.  The NNS data messages appear to be encrypted.

However, from the captured frames, I cannot ascertain:

1. Is TLS 1.2 used?
2. Which encryption cipher suite is used?
3. Is TLS compression disabled?

What should I look for in the TCP and or NNS frames?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a suggestion: for Microsoft open protocol specifications (OSS) you would try to ask the team directly: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/openspecs-windows.html. Questions are handled by MS engineers from OSS team and they have ability to escalate your question to product teams. Just in case if you fail to find answer here.

Comment: @Crypt32, thanks for the suggestion. I asked the same question here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/204137/how-can-i-ascertain-that-net-negotiatestream-ms-nn.html